# Install rpm file from a server

Tags: linux, rpm

I understand how to install an rpm from a given url. Example: RUN `yum -y install http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm`

So that is the easy part.

My question is, how do I do the exact same thing, only with the rpm folder living on my server, and not on a URL

the path on the server for example is /var/opt/project/sphinx-1.3.2-1.x86_64.rpm

I have tried RUN `rpm -ivh /var/opt/project/sphinx-1.3.2-1.x86_64.rpm` But this returns no file or directory.
How can I install the rpm from the server I am on?

Comment: what is the output from above command?

Comment: Here is what I get:
RUN rpm -ivh ./sphinx-1.3.2-1.x86_64.rpm
 ---> Running in 4c4a63fc8ad8
error: open of ./sphinx-1.3.2-1.x86_64.rpm failed: No such file or directory

I have also tried with using /var/opt/project/sphinx-1.3.2-1.x86_64.rpm

I guess another part of the question is when you say rpm -ivh (path) is that the absolute path ?

Comment: and this file sphinx-1.3.2-1.x86_64.rpm exists?

Comment: What is this RUN you refer to. Do you type that in a terminal?

Comment: The run command is in my dockerfile. The dockerfile is a set of instructions to be executed.

so inside of the Dockerfile i tell it RUN rpm -ivh /var/opt/project/sphinx-1.3.2-1.x86_64.rpm

But i keep getting /var/opt/project/sphinx-1.3.2-1.x86_64.rpm failed: No such file or directory

The dockerfile itself is also located in /var/opt/project

Comment: As well i have done a pwd command inside the directory where the sphinx rpm is located and the output from the pwd command is /var/opt/project/sphinx-1.3.2-1.x86_64.rpm

Comment: So you are trying to install rpm file from host to image? If this is the case you should find way to copy rpm file first, and to install.

Comment: Yes, that is actually what turned out happening. Was that with docker the file was not volume mounted in, so basically the command was being ran inside of a container.. and not inside of the directory, or even the terminal where the file was. So what happened was i had to use the volumes command to mount in the file. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is correct - `rpm -ihv <path to RPM file>`. You can also use `yum localinstall <path to RPM file>`. You may be looking in the wrong place for the file, or it may not be the file you think it is if you're getting a "no such file or directory" error. You could also have a problem with your path wherein the `rpm` executable isn't being located.

Comment: I have triedboth ways, with the absolute path, and no path at all just placing the file in the same directory as the Dockerfile. Both return no file or directory. I did a pwd command in the directory with the file and it says /var/opt/project When you cd into /var/opt/project then do an ls -a command the file isthere. 

Could it be an issue that these commands are being ran from a Dockerfile, although I specified the absolute path, perhaps i did that wrong. The command looks exactly like this  RUN rpm -ivh /var/opt/project/sphinx-1.3.2-1.x86_64.rpm 

sphinx.rpm is located in /var/opt/project

Comment: The command [/bin/sh -c rpm -ivh /var/opt/project/sphinx-1.3.2-1.x86_64.rpm] returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: As it turns out this is the correct answer. The issue I had was that this was being ran in a docker container and not on the server where the file was. So I needed to volume mount the file into the container, once I figured that part out, it worked with the commands you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether rpm file is present in the following directory, In your case it is located in /var/opt/project/ .

following no file or directory error return becoz it is unable to find the sp*.rpm
file from the /var/opt/project/ directory.